# Corona SDK: Rotating an object with specific reference point consecutively

Tags: object, rotation, coronasdk

I'm trying to make a square move by rotating it sideways with its reference point set to the bottom side of the direction it is moving to.

For example: if I would move the square to the right, I would set its reference point to the bottom right of it and animate a rotation of 90 degrees, after the movement is done, I increase the square X by the width of it and centrally set its rotation to 90 degrees (so that I can keep track of its position)

The thing is, how should I proceed to keep repeating it? 'cause if I try to rotate by another 90 degrees using bottom right reference point, it won't be using the right position. What should I do to get the new bottom right relative position?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a transparent image twice as wide and high as the square.
Place the square in the top left corner.
Rotating the image around its center will now rotate the square in the way you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some maths to track where the new bottom is, using some simple formula for 2D rotation, so you calculate BEFORE rotating, where the point you wish to modify.

Then you use xReference and yReference variables :)

Comment: i've called my square 'crate' and this is the code I'm trying to use:

crate.xReference = (crate.width * 0.5) * math.cos(toRad(crate.rotation)) - (crate.height*0.5) * math.sin(toRad(crate.rotation));

crate.yReference = (crate.height * 0.5) * math.cos(toRad(crate.rotation)) + (crate.width*0.5) * math.sin(toRad(crate.rotation));

and this works when crate rotation is 0, but it simply won't work after that.

it seems that when i actually move the box around and centrally rotate it afterwards I'm bugging this solution, but I do have to be able to retrieve crate x after each movement.
any thoughs?